# Order limit backtesting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, back-testing

I started to study "backtesting" and during testing I encountered one incomprehensible situation.

```
class MyCandlesStrat(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        super().init()
        self.signal1 = self.I(SIGNAL)

    def next(self):
        super().next()
        if self.signal1==1:
            self.buy()
        elif self.signal1==-1:
            self.sell()
```

above is the strategy test code, but I can't figure out how to indicate that the signal = 0, did it close the order?

UPD : Signal column contains signals. in the code above, only trades are opened and not closed.

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
0
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
```

after a little digging on the net, I added the code
class MyCandlesStrat(Strategy):
def init(self):
super().init()
self.signal1 = self.I(SIGNAL)

```
def next(self):
    super().next()
    if self.signal1 ==1:
        self.position.close()
        self.buy()

    elif self.signal1 ==-1:
        self.position.close()
        self.sell()

    else:
        self.signal1 == 0
        self.position.close()
```

But it's still not what I want. This code closes deals with the same signals and does not

[image: scrin]

I want to understand how to implement "buy and hold until the signal is the same"
or
"sell and hold while the signal is the same" ??

Comment: Your query is not clear enough. If the signal is coming from somewhere, and there is signal with value 0, then doesn't another `elif` statement work, `elif self.signal`==0`?

Comment: UPD my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would probably work for you:

```
if len(self.trades) > 0:
    if self.trades[-1].is_long and <your logic>:
        self.trades[-1].close()
    elif self.trades[-1].is_short and <your logic>:
        self.trades[-1].close()
```

PD: The index for self.trades doesn't have to be the last trade, it's your call which trade you want to close